# ListView Adapter issue

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

```
public class SearchRecipe extends AppCompatActivity {

 ArrayList<Recipe> lst=new ArrayList<Recipe>();
    private ListView listView;
    ProgressDialog pg;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_recipe);
        pg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "please wait", true);
        getDataBase3();
    }

    public void getDataBase3() {
        myFirebaseRef.child("Recipes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Recipe recipe = snapshot.getValue(Recipe.class);
                    lst.add(recipe);
                }
                init();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchRecipe.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }

    private void init() {
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_searchRecipe);
        UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, lst);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SearchRecipe.this,ShowRecipe.class);
                intent.putExtra("recipeName",lst.get(position).getRecipeName());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        pg.dismiss();
    }

    public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Recipe> {
        public UsersAdapter(android.content.Context context, ArrayList<Recipe> names) {
            super(context, 0, names);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Recipe user = getItem(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_row_layout, parent, false);
                TextView tvname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recipeTV2_row);
                TextView tvlike= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likes_row);
                TextView tvdislike= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dislike_row);

                tvname.setText(user.getRecipeName());
                tvlike.setText(""+user.getLikes());
                tvdislike.setText(""+user.getDislikes());
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

The filling of the lst works -  there are values and right ones.
When the list gets to about postions 8 it starts to replace the names in the ListView (if number 8 in list is "dog" and number 1 is "cat" it will show the number 8 and number 1 is both "cat" , but when you click at 1 it will bring it to 1 and when you click at 8 it will bring you to 8 the right one !)

So the problem is with the presentation of the ListView - it shows wrong values and when you click at them it brings you to the right place.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

ListView is deprecated, just use RecyclerView, it is way lighter and easyer to use (if you still going to be having problems - then post it)

RecyclerView sample by google: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Searchable and expandable recycerview samples(within dialog container, tho idea is the same): https://github.com/WithoutCaps/DialogsCheatSheet